# Specifying parameter grid for regression model

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, hyperparameter

I am working with more than one dataset. So, I have to test my Random Forest Model over 4 datasets. The parameter grid I am taking for dataset D1 is not producing good results for dataset D2 and so on. I have tried multiple range of parameters but none is working for all datasets. Please suggest if their is any empirical/ analytical way by which I can set a common parameter grid for all datasets.

Comment: Why should all of the models use the same parameters?

Comment: Not the exact same parameters, but I am asking for the common grid of parameters. It is basically asked for reporting purpose.